# How to avoid command not found when running bash command in Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to construct a Makefile that is able to execute some commands inside docker or in a local bash. So, I tried something like this:

```
BASH_CMD := bash -c
DOCKER_CMD := docker exec api bash -c
RUN_CMD = $(BASH_CMD)

ifeq ($(USE_DOCKER), true)
    RUN_CMD = $(DOCKER_CMD)
endif

flake8:
    @echo "<<< Running flake8 >>>"
    $(RUN_CMD) "flake8 ."
```

The problem is that the environment variable `USE_DOCKER` is not been loaded (I am exporting it) and flake8 step gives me the following error:

```
bash: flake8: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:11: flake8] Erro 127
```

When I try to run `flake8 .` directly in the bash it works nice. I tried to export the path too, but without success.

How can I solve it? Is there another better approach? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I recommend you try `BASH_CMD := /bin/sh -c` and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you, @MadScientist!! The problem is that I was trying to run the Makefile with sudo.

Comment: It's always helpful to show the exact command you invoked, along with the errors.  If we'd have known about the sudo we'd have almost certainly been able to solve the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to `sudo` command. The root user does not have the packages or environment variables available to use.

Instead of the following command:

```
sudo make flake8
```

This one solves the problem:

```
make flake8
```